# Conversion is not accurate

Tags: c, arrays, char, type-conversion

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char z[] = "9,8 2,8 3,4 2,7 0,3";
    int size = sizeof z / sizeof *z;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%c", z[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    char *dez = strtok(z, " ");
    printf("%s\n", dez);
    float z = atof(dez);

    printf("%1.1f\n", z);

    return 0;
}
```

this is what i get at the console :
9,8 2,8 3,4 2,7 0,3

9,8

9

I just need to convert dez to float and print it out.
I used 1.1%f because the Result should be displayed in that form.
At the end i get 9 instead of 9,8 ,the code should be correct any suggestions on how to solve this ?

Comment: `float` values have a `.` in them, not a `,`

Comment: I thought atof was locale sensitive. Maybe you need an explicit call to setlocale() first to make sure it knows you're using a comma decimal point.

Comment: @Rup `atof` always [uses the "C" locale](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/).

Comment: @AdrianMole I read that as "when in C locale" not "atof always uses C locale". [Test gist](https://gist.github.com/RupW/c5dcf0b0ceee428e8b53a2682af6a9e5) - both GCC (or glib I suppose) and MSVC do read the comma for me in de_DE locale, but oddly the compiler on repl.it doesn't.

Comment: Programs start out in the "C" locale.  You have to call `setlocale()` to change the default.  Usually, that means specifying the empty string as the new locale — to set the system default locale.